# Accessing the background-image in gsp in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

```
<div id="Canvas" 
 style="background-image: url(../../assets/images/doctor/ecg/ecg_back.png);
 position:relative; height:250px;width:1000px;">
```

how to access the image present in assets/images/doctor/ecg/ecg_back.png from the set the background image in gsp present in the views/ECGView.gsp

Comment: what do you mean by "access"?

Comment: i mean to set the background image in gsp using the image present in the assets/images/ folder

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access the image as a resource.

```
<div id="Canvas" style="background-image:url('${resource(dir: "images/doctor/ecg/", file: "ecg_back.png")}');height: 250px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;width:1000px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `assetPath` taglib to do that. For example:

```
<div style="background-image: url(${assetPath(src: '/whatever/path/under/assets/image.png')});">...</div>
```